# Google Chrome Stable crashing at launch

Tags: google-chrome, crash, browser

After a recent update in Ubuntu 16.04 chrome refused to launch with the following output to terminal:

```
~$ google-chrome-stable
[5525:5562:0327/115046.503718:ERROR:nss_util.cc(724)] After loading Root   Certs, loaded==false: NSS error code: -8018
[5525:5550:0327/115046.527819:ERROR:in_progress_cache_impl.cc(93)] Could  not read download entries from file because there was a read failure.
--2018-03-27 11:50:46--  https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
Resolving clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)... 216.58.213.110,  2a00:1450:4009:811::200e
Connecting to clients2.google.com   (clients2.google.com)|216.58.213.110|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘/dev/fd/4’

Crash dump id: 77bf82c7db6d1e8e

     0K                                                         602K=0s

Bus error (core dumped)
```

I tried purging chrome with `sudo apt purge google-chrome-stable` and reinstalling but it still wouldn't launch even after a reboot.

Comment: I experienced this when going from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 20.04. The upgrade leaves google-chrome-stable installed, but it should have been uninstalled and replaced with chromium-browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing that worked was purging both `google-chrome-stable` and `chromium-browser` with `sudo apt purge google-chrome-stable` and `sudo apt purge chromium-browser` and then deleting any files and folders which point to chrome or chromium under `~./cache/` and `~./config/`. eg. `rm -r ~/.cache/google-chrome/` etc.

Answer (score 2):

On a raspberry pi ( Chromium 65.0.3325.181 Built on Raspbian , running on Raspbian 9.4) , if you get the message:
ERROR:in_progress_cache_impl.cc(93) Could not read download entries from file because there was a read failure.
Segmentation fault

Start chromium from Terminal and type the following:

chromium-browser --temp-profile

This will bypass some errors in the cache directory

Answer (score 1):

This is probably caused by missing of NSS library or an old version of them. Try to install them:

```
sudo apt-get install libnss3
sudo apt-get update
```

In case do the purge and reboot before installing them.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution mentioned above worked but only for a couple of days, after that I encountered the same issue again, and end-up fixing by installing gnome-keyring:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-keyring
```

Yet I'm not sure what exactly is going on and why gnome-keyring wasn't installed, I guess this is as well related with my last apt dist-upgrade.